# How to get date value with onChange?

Tags: typescript, date, input, onchange

So i have this code

Date Picker

```
<input
    type='date'
    id='sDate'
    onChange={functionSDateChange}
/>
```

Function
`functionSDateChange: () => console.log('Start date changed to' + document.getElementById('sDate'))`

I was expecting the output to be the date I selected, but the console.log only shows the following:
`Start date changed to[object HTMLInputElement]`

Can you show me the correct way to get the date value onChange?

I already tried:

```
const val = document.getElementById('sDate')
functionSDateChange: () => console.log('Start date changed to' + val)
```

But it shows like this:
`Start date changed tonull`

Comment: Try `() => console.log('Start date changed to' + document.getElementById('sDate').value)`.

Comment: @Dogbert it shows two errors like this Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement' & Object is possibly 'null'.

Comment: I already found a way to fix it
`'Start date changed to ' + (document.getElementById('sDate') as HTMLInputElement).value`

Comment: Not sure if this helps but onChange passes a variable to your function that you can use inside your function like this 
`functionSDateChange: (val) => console.log('Start date changed to' + val);`
there is an example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your example you can do it like this:

```
<input
    type='date'
    id='sDate'
    onChange={(val) => functionSDateChange(val)} // val is the new value after change
/>
```

And then you can declare your function later like this:

```
const functionSDateChange: (val: TypeOfValue) => void = (val) => {
    console.log('This is the new value ' + val);
}
```

Hope that helps! Let me know if you need more explanation about the types or anything else. Anyway you can find more info about the onChange [here:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)